# Batch for loop with array

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm trying to build a batch script that includes a for loop as long as my array is.
so my problem is that the command that should be executed in every loop is not working correctly. The command:

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,25) do ResourceHacker.exe -open "das/%%a[%%i]%%" -save "das/%%a[%%i]%%" -action addoverwrite -resource Resources.res
```

just write das/%%a[%%i]%% for the file path not the real file path that is in the array. Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Commandline:
ResourceHacker.exe  -open "das\%a[20]%" -save "das\%a[20]%" -action addoverwrite -resource Resources.res

Open    : C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker\das\%a[20]%
Save    : C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker\das\%a[20]%
Error: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker\das\%a[20]%" does not exist
Failed!

Comment: Okay thanks and how should i the command? i´m not very good in Batch. if set a array `set a[0]=afnCollectionRt.bpl` and this should be placed in the path

Comment: Just put `call` right before `ResourceHacker.exe`…

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using array like variables, note you need `delayedexpansion`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "a[0]=afnCollectionRt.bpl"
for /l %%i in (0,1,25) do ResourceHacker.exe -open "das\!a[%%i]!" -save "das\!a[%%i]!" -action addoverwrite -resource Resources.res
```